# .htaccess Redirect To Another Site's Homepage Only If URL Don't Exist

Tags: .htaccess

So this is what I'm trying to accomplish, and I'll do my best to explain...

Through the .htaccess file, I'm attempting to redirect all pages of one site to another site, but ONLY if the URL doesn't exist. If the URL exists, then do nothing. Load that URL. If the URL doesn't exist, redirect to the homepage of another site.

So, going to www.johnny.com/boxing (no files) or even just www.johnny.com (no files) would redirect to www.johnpunches.com, since neither of those URLs work. And that would work for any URL on www.johnny.com that doesn't exist. It would simply redirect to the index page of www.johnpunches.com

However, going to www.johnny.com/members (where there is a working directory) would actually go to that URL and not redirect, because the page exists.

So, again, if the URL exists, then do nothing. Load that URL. If the URL doesn't exist, redirect to the homepage of another site.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
# File does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Directory does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Redirect to new domain if the above were missing
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.google.com/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Change out google.com to whatever domain you are redirecting to.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to get some assistance from another thread and put this together:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^johnny.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.johnny.com/$1 [r=301,nc,l]
RewriteRule !^folder($|/) http://www.johnkicks.com [L,R=301]
```

In the example above, the "folder" can be replaced with any directory that works. The second and third line force the www version of the site before the final rule has run so that any URL that DOES work, like johnny.com/folder would redirect to www.johnny.com/folder.

Two questions:

- Did I do it correctly? Does the order of my rules work? Should I be doing it any differently?
- Would I have to duplicate that fourth line for every working directory?